# Can't convert python file to exe file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I can't convert my python file to exe file when i use uic. Loadui () module,  when i try to convert ui to py file it works but it's will be so difficult to do all work again in this file

Comment: Please add some error messages and more details before anyone can really help you.

Comment: You should make your answer more specific, preferably accompanied with some form of demonstration or code.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the `.ui` file to Python file can be done automatically using the `pyuic4` (PyQt4) or `pyuic5` command.

**Don't edit the `.py` file that `pyuic5` produces!**. Instead import the generated .py file into another file, as you would any other module/class.

```
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
```

You only need to re-run this command if you make changes to your `.ui` file again.

If you really don't want to do this, you need to bundle the `.ui` file into your executable. Check the documentation for the bundling system you're using (e.g. PyInstaller) and look for how to bundle data files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command on terminal:

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x "C:\Path\to\.ui\file.ui" -o "C:\Path\to\.ui\file.py"
```

Then, you can use **pyinstaller** module to convert your .py to .exe using:

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller file_name.py [options1] [options2]
```

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#options) you can find the list of all options if you need it.